# F# program flow question with Async and Option

Tags: asynchronous, f#, computation-expression

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to accomplish the following task in F#. The following is a simplified C# pseudocode equivalent I'm looking to replicate.

```
var x = await GetXAsync();
if (x == null) return "not found";
var y = await GetYAsync(x);
return y;
```

My initial F# version looks something like:

```
task {
    let! x = GetXAsync()
    match x with
    | None -> // need to return a hard-coded value here
    | Some x` -> 
                 let! y = GetYAsync(x`)
                 // More code
                 // return some value based on y here
}
```

Obviously this is terrible, but I'm unsure of how to proceed. Should I attempt a full ROP style of programming here, or is there something simpler?

Comment: With just two values, `x` and `y`, I don't think there's a need for a full-fledged ROP solution. What you have looks just fine to me; I don't agree with you that it is "terrible". Sometimes the simple solution is best.

Comment: Well, is it just that piece of code, or does the pattern continues drawing a stairway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are returning the `"not found"` string to indicate that something went wrong  from a function that otherwise returns strings. I would not do this, because it will be hard to distinguish between the case where everything worked and the case where it did not.

If the fact that `GetXAsync` returns `null` is something that indicates a failure, then I'd just use exceptions. F# async has a nice support for propagating those and you can catch them using `try .. with`. There is nothing wrong with using exceptions in F# to handle exceptional situations!

```
exception InvalidX of string

let GetXAsync() = async { 
  // whetever code that calculates 'failed' and 'result' goes here
  if failed then raise (InvalidX "not found")
  return result }
```

Then you can just call the functions and exceptions get propagated automatically.

```
async {
  let! x = GetXAsync() 
  let! y = GetYAsync(x)
  return y }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The example code was really just to show the structure and I should have been more clear about that. In reality, I'm coding a handler for Giraffe and either need to return a 404 or some JSON data. I'll work on making this more clear. I was pretty tired when I wrote it. BTW, your book is great!